# How to read or parse CRL with PHP

Tags: php, x509certificate

The code below works for "user certificates" or "certificate authority certificates"
The generated Pem file is like this

*-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

MIIEVDCCAzygAwIBAgIBBTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBgMQswCQYDVQQGEwJGUjEZ

...

3zk8lbSs5UE=

-----END CERTIFICATE-----*

And I get the information about the certificate which I can use easily afterwards.
In particular the issuer and the timestamps (and others informations)

```
function derToPem($contentFonc,$typeFonc="")
{
    $response = "";

    if($contentFonc!="")
    {
        $response = chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFonc), 64, "\n");

        if($typeFonc!="crl")    $response = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".$response."-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
        else $response = "-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----\n".$response."-----END X509 CRL-----\n";
  }

  return($response);
}


// Personnal Function That Return Certificat in DER (Binary) Format
$certificateContentDer = extractLdapQuery();

// Conversion DER to PEM
$certificateContentPem = derToPem($certificateContentDer);

// Extraction Information
$listeInfoCertificate   = openssl_x509_parse($certificateContentPem);
```

But I would also like to do the same for a CRL.
My function "derToPem" works fine.
I compared to a transformed pem with the "openssl crl" command and the files are identical (encapsuled with the text "... X509 CRL...")
But I don't know how to extract information from this "crl.pem" file.
openssl_x509_parse function doesn't work.
I would like to be able to extract the issuer and the dates (last update and next update).
I know it's possible with "openssl crl" command like this "**openssl crl -in my_file_crl.pem -noout -issuer**"
But how to do this with PHP...?
I searched on Net before ask here but I don't find.
It's not possible in PHP...? Without running the openssl command and getting its output..?

Comment: You could [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) that `openssl crl -in my_file_crl.pem -noout -issuer` command

Comment: @brombeer Thank you for your answer but as I specify in my question, I would like to know if it is possible to achieve this in PHP without using the command "openssl crl" and getting its output. If I can do it in PHP it avoids creating a file on disk, I would only work with variables (as is the case for user certificates)

Comment: There's an [open bug/patch](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40046) from a while ago that appears to have what you are looking for, so it appears that the answer is still "not possible at this time using the native extension". It is for creating, but I'm guessing parsing would be related to this, too.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for your response and link. I will look at it. Even if it's not possible, maybe this link will help me find some solutions.